# Glyphicon not showing for Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have searched things here and not sure why the ratings stars using angular-ui bootstrap isn't showing the glyphicons. The console shows errors, but not sure how they are applied here as the fonts show correctly according to my gulp build.js and whatnot.

The image showing the missing fonts with the console errors:

[image]

Any ideas whatsoever? I tried manually copying fonts, etc...., but no luck.

Thanks much.

Adding my gulp build.js:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('partials', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
    path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
  ])
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
      module: 'mbapp',
      root: 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/font-awesome/fonts', '../fonts'))    
    .pipe($.cssnano())
    .pipe($.rev())
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
  });

// Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
// Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,otf,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '../fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('other', function () {
  var fileFilter = $.filter(function (file) {
    return file.stat.isFile();
  });

  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.{html,css,js,scss}')
  ])
    .pipe(fileFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return $.del([path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/')]);
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'other']);
```

Comment: I don't think it's an AngularJS problem, but rather a bootstrap problem. It's looking for the fonts in a specific place, did you put your fonts where he is looking for ?

Comment: yes it looks like that only.please check the path you given for that icon

Comment: Problem though is that it works locally, but when I run my gulp build and whatnot to push to server, then it loses track. This location is specified in my build.js which I have added above and the fonts are there from what I see.

Comment: Anyone got help on this? I know it isn't a angular problem, but the tooling I am using is angular-ui.

Comment: having exactly the same issue. The search continues...